# How to Check Whether an Array (or List) Contains Another an Array (List) Using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to get the list of files (file is an entity) which has the selected services (service is another entity). The file can have many services.

I tried the following statement, but it does not give the correct results:

```
var _serviceTypes = viewModel.SelectedServiceTypes;
// _serviceTypes is an array of integers

var resultsTemp = repository.Files.Where(f => f.Services.Select(s => s.ServiceTypeID).Intersect(_serviceTypes).Any());
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:

_serviceTypes in an array of integers: {int[2]}

The files can have many services, each of which as one service type id (integer)

For instance, a file has two services in it: ambulance (service type id: 3) and hospitalization (service type id: 5). I want to get all the files which have both the services in it.

Comment: Are you trying to get all the files whose Id is inside the _serviceTypes list/array ?

Comment: Can you show what's in `_serviceTypes` when this runs, and what's in `resultsTemp` afterward?

Comment: What you have seems right. How do you know it is not correct?

Comment: Please be more precise. Should a single file contain any service from the list or all services from the list?

Comment: @grek40 The file should contain all the services from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the following operations should answer your question:

```
// requested IDs
var requestedIDs = new List<int>();
// the IDs from one file
var IDsInFile = new List<int>();
if (requestedIDs.Except(IDsInFile).Any())
{
    // at least some requested IDs are not in the file
}
else
{
    // all requested IDs are in the file
}
if (requestedIDs.Intersect(IDsInFile).Any())
{
    // at least some requested IDs are in the file
}
else
{
    // not a single requested ID is in the file
}
```

Since you want every file that contains all of the requested services, the correct query would be

```
var _serviceTypes = viewModel.SelectedServiceTypes;
// _serviceTypes is an array of integers

var resultsTemp = repository.Files.Where(f => !_serviceTypes.Except(f.Services.Select(s => s.ServiceTypeID)).Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if a single element exists in both lists, which is probably not what you had in mind. Try to check if the intersection is equal to the smaller list (assuming it's `_serviceTypes`, as that's not evident from your code):

```
var resultsTemp = repository.Files
                            .Where(f => f.Services.Select(s => s.ServiceTypeID)
                            .Intersect(_serviceTypes)
                            .OrderBy(x => x)
                            .SequenceEqual(_serviceTypes.OrderBy(x => x));
```